# sharedpreferences doesn't save data

Tags: android

i want to save data in the first activity and use it in the second activity, on the first activity i used this:

```
android.content.SharedPreferences someData;
public static String filename = "mySharedString";
someData = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor editor = someData.edit();
editor.putString("HostIP", "192.168.1.101");
```

in the second activity i used this

```
android.content.SharedPreferences someData;
TextView Message;
public static String filename = "mySharedString";
String HostIP;
someData = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
HostIP = someData.getString("HostIP", "0");
phoneNumber.setText(HostIP);
```

but the results prints on phonenumber is `0` not `192.168.1.101`

Answer (score 4):

After editing data in sharedPrefrence, [commit()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#commit%28%29) it.

```
editor.commit();
```

- [See here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Comment: it works, really 3 hours of finding the error, thank you , i will accept answer after 11mins